# How to specify field name

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity, yaml

I had next entity with yaml format:

```
BW\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    repositoryClass: BW\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 25
            unique: true
        password:
            type: string
            length: 64
        email:
            type: string
            length: 60
            unique: true
        isActive:
            type: boolean
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Now, when I update scheme, I get `isActive` field name in DB, same as property name.
How can I specify property name `isActive` like `is_active` field name in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a column name like this:

```
BW\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    repositoryClass: BW\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 25
            unique: true
        password:
            type: string
            length: 64
        email:
            type: string
            length: 60
            unique: true
        isActive:
            type: boolean
            column: is_active
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

More on that - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping

Comment: I used `name` instead of `column`, with `column` it work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the column name for the database

```
fields:
    username:
        type: string
        length: 25
        unique: true
    password:
        type: string
        length: 64
    email:
        type: string
        length: 60
        unique: true
    isActive:
        type: boolean
        column: is_active
```

Answer (score 0):

You dealing with two different kind of conventions here. It is common in Symfony to use camel case for naming variables. Within databases you often find this underscore written names. If you access your isActive property your entity model will map it to the is_active column in the database.